# Find prefixes and suffixes of a string

Tags: c#

Say we have a string "bread", I want to get all prefixes and suffixes of the string. The definition of it as the image below.

prefixes:

> b,br,bre,brea

suffixes:

> read,ead,ad,d

[image: string]

Now I only can get the prefixes and I think it is wrong.

```
string pattern = "bread";
var prefixes = pattern.Where(x => x.ToString().StartsWith(pattern.Substring(0, 1))).ToList();
```

Comment: FYI, your current code doesn't get prefixes, it gets one prefix, the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
string pattern = "bread";
var prefixes = Enumerable.Range(1, pattern.Length - 1)
                         .Select(p => pattern.Substring(0, p));
var suffixes = Enumerable.Range(1, pattern.Length - 1)
                         .Select(p => pattern.Substring(p, pattern.Length - p));
```

---

If you don't need the results in a collection you might just want to use a simple for-loop as Dave Zych posted.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just loop?

```
string s = "bread";
for(int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, i)); //prefix
    Console.WriteLine(s.SubString(i, s.Length - i)); //suffix
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer LINQ.

Comment: Sometimes loops are better. LINQ is awesome, no doubt, but compare the readability of the accepted answer to the readability of this loop. This will actually be more efficient too, just one loop compared to at least four (2 for creating ranges, 2 for each select). LINQ isn't always the best option.

Comment: @CurtisRutland I couldn't have said it better myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> prefixes = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
{
    prefixes.Add(myString.Substring(0,i));
}
List<string> sufixes = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
{
    sufixes.Add(myString.Substring(i,myString Length - i));
}
```